# Как преобразовать строковое булево значение в тип?

Tags: javascript

Как преобразовать строки вида `true` или `false` в встроенный булев тип JS?
<sub>[Перевод вопроса "How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **`let bValue = sValue.toLowerCase().trim() === 'true';`**

[`String#toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) и [`String#trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) преобразуют строку в нижний регистр и убирают пробелы с конца/начала.
Чтобы успешно преобразовывались значения `TRUE`, `TrUe`, `True`. etc.
Если Вы точно знаете какой будет строка, можете убрать

---

Остерегайтесь ловушек не самого очевидного поведения в хитром JS:

```
let myBool = Boolean("false"); // == true (о_О; не пустая строка (в т. ч. и только пробельные символы) приводится к true)
let myBool = !!"false";        // == true (в общем-то одно и то же)
```

Наглядное пояснение о [приведении типов](https://learn.javascript.ru/types-conversion).

---

Можно воспользоваться JSON:

```
JSON.parse("true");
```

Плюс в том, что можно скормить всё, без проверок (на строку, на формат, на пробелы, etc), он сам проверит и выкинет ошибку, если есть, минус - разворачивать парсер для такой пустяковой операции довольно странно (хотя на современных движках разница в памяти/времени будет невелика).

---

Если булево значение предстаёт в ином представлении (`1|0`, `on|off`, `hot|cold`, etc) и может быть любым из них, то проще обойтись регулярным выражением:

```js
console.info(['true', 'fFlSe ', '  1 ', 'OfF', 'hOt'].map(_ => /^(?:true|1|on|hot)$/i.test(_.trim()))); // [true,false,true,false,true]
```

Т. е. перечисляем все значения, которые представляют `true`.
Хорошая статья по основам регулярных выражений есть в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: Почему бы вместо trim не включить пробельные символы в регулярку? И почему первый кусок кода в цитате? И убери leпоменяй let на var.

Comment: @Qwertiy, пост специально для новичков, не стоит перегружать регулярку, наверное.

Comment: @vp_arth, match массив строк вернет или null, а не булевское значение

Comment: Ладно, изменю ответ, только не уходите :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте `eval`, толоко не злоупотребляйте.

```
var a = "true".toLowerCase();
var b = eval(a);
```

Теперь `a == true`.

Comment: **Don't use evil!**

Comment: @Other eval is evil, но в этом случае его юзать можно

Comment: Зачем бессмысленно нагружать интерпретатор? И учить новичков плохим манерам?

Comment: @Other я же написал _не злоупотреблять eval'ом_.

Comment: Злоупотреблять - использовать что-то, когда можно обойтись и без этого. Выходит Вы злоупотребляете, но рекомендуете другим не злоупотреблять.

Comment: @Other тем не менее, у меня код короче

Comment: Вот давайте не будем мериться :)

Comment: @Other так и знал)